# filter file with numeric column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an excel file with the following structure

```
ColumnA  ColumnB
NA       NA
Coord    Value
(1,2,3)  -23
(4,5,6)  -56
```

I need to do the following:

Filter out rows that only have a numeric column in Column B

Once I filter out the rows, I need to create 3 columns from Column A

So for the above, I need a data set that looks like

```
x   y   z   value
1   2   3   -23
4   5   6   -56
```

For starters, when I import the dataset, all columns a 'chr' and I'm having trouble forcing Column B to be numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert `ColumnB` to numeric and select rows which are not turned to `NA`. Remove opening and closing round brackets from the string and use `separate` to get data in different columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(as.numeric(ColumnB))) %>%
  mutate(ColumnA = gsub('[()]', '', ColumnA)) %>%
  tidyr::separate(ColumnA, into = c("A", "B", "C"), sep = ",")

#  A B C ColumnB
#1 1 2 3     -23
#2 4 5 6     -56
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(NA, "Coord", "(1,2,3)", "(4,5,6)"), ColumnB = c(NA,
"Value", "-23", "-56")),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following is another approach. Your data is called `foo`. The two columns in `foo` are in character now. First, I get rows that contain numeric characters. Then, I used `extract()` to get numeric characters in `ColumnA`. The function can create three columns while it extracts the characters. Finally, I changed the column name (ColumnB) to value as you specified.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

filter(foo, grepl(x = ColumnB, pattern = "\\d+")) %>% 
extract(col = "ColumnA", into = c("x", "y", "z"),
        regex = "(\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)") %>%
rename(value = "ColumnB")

#  x y z value
#1 1 2 3   -23
#2 4 5 6   -56
```

**DATA**

```
foo <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(NA, "Coord", "(1,2,3)", "(4,5,6)"), 
ColumnB = c(NA, "Value", "-23", "-56")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: @RonakShah Yeah sure. What about something like `"(?<=-|^)\\d+"`? If you have another regex idea, let me know.

Comment: @RonakShah We do not know how OP's data is like most of the time. If we take assumptions, that can be an endless work. Yet, I think it is good to think some potential situations, as you were thinking.

Comment: @RonakShah No worries. I think SO is one of the places where people can help one another to be able to think and write codes better. I appreciate your thought.